# Move an array with his headers in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I have been trying to transfer an array from a sheet (sheet 2) to an other (sheet5) and to rename the new one so that I do not get confused using them.
My problem is that I get all the values available in the array transfered, but I miss the headers that I want to use again on the sheet5. The code is simple but I don't know where I can add something to get the headers.

Code :

```
Sheets("Equipement").Select 'Equipement is the Sheet2
Sheets(2).Range("Tableau_equipement").Select 'Tableau_equipement is the name of the array from Sheet2
Selection.Copy Sheets(5).Range("A5") 'pasting the array on the Sheet5.
```

I also add two screenshots : (the first one being the one present on Sheet2 and the second one being the results on Sheet5) :
[image: Sheet2]

[image: results]

Thanks for help, feel free to ask more details and excuse my poor English.

Comment: You are working with a table or `ListObject`... so `ListObject.Range.Copy` should bring everything over.

Comment: So "Tableau_equipement" is a ListObject ?  Excuse me I am kinda new to VBA and programmation in general. I just tried ListObject.Range("Tableau_equipement").Select but got an error.

Comment: `Sheets("Equipment").ListObjects(1).Range.Copy Sheets(5).Range("A5")`.

Comment: Oh ok so a ListObject doesn't have a name but just a number ? I guess there is a way to name it, but thank you for your help it works perfectly !

Comment: You can also refer to a `ListObject` by name: `Sheets("Equipment").ListObjects("Tableau_equipement")`.

Comment: Ok thanks  for the tips !

Answer (score 1):

Final code to close the answer :

```
Sheets("Equipement").ListObjects(1).Range.Copy Sheets(5).Range("A5")
```

Comment: Yes, I just didn't thought of removing it, it's just to stay on the sheet because I have some more code that changes the displayed sheet. Thanks for noticing it anyway.